# Can axion fields make the gravitational constant to oscillate in harmonic way?

Tags: gravity, modified-gravity, axion

Axions (and more generally, I think scalar fields) can make fundamental constants to vary. Does it include the gravitational constant? And if so, can it be make to oscillate as a simple harmonic oscillator?

Answer (score 0):

Variations of the gravitational constant (or any other constants) are not standardly induced by axion fields. Some scalar fields can however create such a variation in a meaningful way, as the ones in the [Brans-Dike theory] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brans%E2%80%93Dicke_theory). It is quite hard to build a consistent theory in which $G$ changes with time (also $G$ is a dimensional constant, and it makes more sense to induce variations of dimensionless numbers as $\alpha_G$, for more on this, see for example [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0208093).)

The evolution of $G$ will follow the one of the field in different ways depending on the model. It will not oscillate as a simple harmonic oscillator as it has to evolve in a more complicated way along with the energy density in the universe. However it is possible for it to oscillate if the field's potential has a specific shape.